# c# Display the data in the List view

Tags: c#

```
private void displayResultsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gameResultsListView.Items.Clear();

        //foreach (Game game in footballLeagueDatabase.games)
        //{
            ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem();
            row.SubItems.Add(game.HomeTeam.ToString());
            row.SubItems.Add(game.HomeScore.ToString());
            row.SubItems.Add(game.AwayTeam.ToString());
            row.SubItems.Add(game.AwayScore.ToString());
            gameResultsListView.Items.Add(row);
       // }
        //footballLeagueDatabase.games.Sort();
    }
   }
}
```

This is the display button and the following code describes the add button.

```
private void addGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((homeTeamTxt.Text.Length) == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a Home Team");
        else if (homeScoreUpDown.Maximum <= 9 && homeScoreUpDown.Minimum >= 0)
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter one digit between 0 and 9");
        else if ((awayTeamTxt.Text.Length) == 0)
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter a Away Team");
        else if (awayScoreUpDown.Maximum <= 9 && awayScoreUpDown.Minimum >= 0)
            MessageBox.Show("You must enter one digit between 0 to 9");
        else 
        {
            //checkGameInputFields();
            game = new Game(homeTeamTxt.Text, int.Parse(homeScoreUpDown.Value.ToString()), awayTeamTxt.Text, int.Parse(awayScoreUpDown.Value.ToString()));
            MessageBox.Show("Home Team" + 't' + homeTeamTxt.Text + "Away Team" + awayTeamTxt.Text + "created");
            footballLeagueDatabase.AddGame(game);

            //clearCreateStudentInputFields();
        }
    }
```

I need to insert data into the above text field and Numeric up down control and display them in the list view.
But I dont know How to do it, because when I press the button "Display Results" it displays the error message.

If you know how can I display the data in the list view, please let me know.This is the first time I am using List view.

Comment: Unhandled exception has occured in your applicationIf you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue.If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object 


this is the error message

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: The followinng message is the whole error message,
The error occurs in the following method


private void displayResultsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Becuase when I check the details of the error it  gives me this method name.
I think the error is in the body of this method I dont totally know how to insert the data into the List View.

Comment: Check my answer. The error is in the game object. If you replace the game.*.ToString() with actual strings like "Home", "10", etc.. you will not get that error.

Comment: Is it in the addGameButton_Click method or displayResultsButton_Click method?

Comment: In the diaplaytresultsButton I hav got already .ToString() in the row commands.

Comment: If the program is crashing when you click on DisplayResults, then the problem is in those game object that you are using to populate the subitems. The error means that you haven't instantiated game, so it is not referencing any object. Look at my updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message that you specified, I believe that your problem is that the game object that you use to create the subitems is not instantiated. I noticed that you commented out the foreach that created this object. So, make sure that you create the object called game.

In addition to this you didn't specify how you wanted the data to appear. If you want all subitems to appear in one row, then you also need to add columns - unless you have already done this using the designer that is. Otherwise your code needs to be something like this:

```
private void displayResultsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Game game = new Game("Home", 10, "Away", 12);

    gameResultsListView.Items.Clear();
    //You need this so that the subitems are also displayed, otherwise
    //only the main item will show in the listview
    gameResultsListView.View = View.Details;

    ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem("Game 1");
    row.SubItems.Add(game.HomeTeam.ToString());
    row.SubItems.Add(game.HomeScore.ToString());
    row.SubItems.Add(game.AwayTeam.ToString());
    row.SubItems.Add(game.AwayScore.ToString());

    //The main item and each subitem get a column in the listView
    gameResultsListView.Columns.Add("Game", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    gameResultsListView.Columns.Add("HomeTeam", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    gameResultsListView.Columns.Add("HomeTeamScore", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    gameResultsListView.Columns.Add("AwayTeam", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    gameResultsListView.Columns.Add("AwayTeamScore", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    gameResultsListView.Items.Add(row);
}
```

Notice how I am creating a Game object at the top. If the above code works, then the problem was with the game object not being instantiated in your original code. If it works you at least know that the problem is not within this function. Also, are you testing the application from within the IDE, because if you are you should have been getting more messages than just the one you showed and it would take you to the line that is causing problems.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation it works properly and then I got same error for the following code in the same MainMenu.cs file, when I try to insert the game.It doesnt happen preiously.
 
I will attch the code like the second comment.The following space is not enough.

Comment: private void addGameButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
I cant comment this code but its in my first question.I changed its two lines as follows 
            else if (homeScoreUpDown.Value > 9 || homeScoreUpDown.Minimum < 0)
                MessageBox.Show("You must enter one digit between 0 and 9");
            else if (homeScoreUpDown.Value > 9 || homeScoreUpDown.Value < 0)
                MessageBox.Show("You must enter one digit between 0 to 9");

Can you please explain me where does the error occur?

Comment: @Kumu can you be a little more specific about the error. So, are you now getting the reference error directly after you click the addGameButton? OR are you getting it if you remove the line that creates a game in the displayReultsButton, trying to create a game with addGameButton, then clicking of displayResultsButton? You should update the original question, so that you can show what the code looks like now. Try putting a break point in the addGameButton and see where it crashes - this will make it easier to see where the error might be.

Comment: I updated my question as a new question.Please try to refer it.
The question heading is Exeception Error in c#.

Comment: @Kumu I found the question and you already have several people pointing to the cause of the error, which is footballLeagueDatabase being null. I would look at where you create the MainMenu form and make sure that you are actually sending a footballLeagueDatabase that is instantiated. As a note for the future though, it is best to update the original question instead of opening another one, because if the two are similar, one might get closed.