# Pass the values from ListView control to text boxes in c#

Tags: c#, listview

```
private void deleteDisplayGamesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Game game = new Game(homeTeamComboBox.Text, int.Parse(homeScoreUpDown.Value.ToString()), awayTeamComboBox.Text, int.Parse(awayScoreUpDown.Value.ToString()));

    deleteDisplayGamesListView.Items.Clear();
    deleteDisplayGamesListView.View = View.Details;

    foreach (Game currentgame in footballLeagueDatabase.games)
    {
        ListViewItem row = new ListViewItem();
        row.SubItems.Add(currentgame.HomeTeam.ToString());
        row.SubItems.Add(currentgame.HomeScore.ToString());
        row.SubItems.Add(currentgame.AwayTeam.ToString());
        row.SubItems.Add(currentgame.AwayScore.ToString());
        deleteDisplayGamesListView.Items.Add(row);
    }
}
```

I need to pass the values from above ListView control to following text boxes when I use the deleteDisplayGamesListView_SelectedIndexChanged method.

```
private void deleteDisplayGamesListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    deleteModifyHomeTeamTxt.Text = "";
    deleteModifyHomeScoreUpDown.Text = "";
    deleteModifyAwayTeamTxt.Text = "";
    deleteModifyAwayScoreUpDown.Text = "";

    foreach (Game currentgame in footballLeagueDatabase.games);
    {
        ?-----------------------------
    }
}
```

Futhermore I need to clear the row after inserting to the textboxes,which i selected from the ListView Control.

If you know how to do this please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704531/c-display-the-data-in-the-list-view

Comment: You should accept the ones that are "working"

Comment: Sorry I have updated now all my working answers and I will do it continously.

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to your `deleteDisplayGamesListView` from within the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler.

This should let you access the `ListViewItem`s and their `SubItem`s.

Comment: Yes I could access to the List view data, when I click that it automatically highlighted, but I need to add those data into the text boxes.